# JQL how to get velocity of component per sprint?

Tags: jira, confluence, jql

We have reports in Confluence. We have 20 components. 
We want to show to target and accepted velocity for the sprint in Confluence for each Component.
Is there a JQL function and query that will provide this?

Answer (score 0):

You may mean Jira instead of Confluence?
In Jira you would have to have a different board for each component.
And then use the boards for reporting only I think
Perhaps there is a plugin out there that lets you do this, not sure